# FreeTDS ODBC error "The identifier that starts with ... is too long. Maximum length is 128."

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pyodbc, freetds, unixodbc

I've been using pyodbc and free TDS to a submit queries to a microsoft SQL-2012 without issue for a while now but have recently stumbled on an issue.
When I submit a longer query I get an error message saying that one of the identifiers is too long and the script crashes.
The EXACT same query works in management studio and doesn't even return a warning.
I've added the following to my code with no avail.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
```

The piece of code that the error is referring to is here:

```
(ZR_KOPF.ZRK_DDP_B IN ('190/TEMP.AA1H', '190/RAIN.AA1H', '190/WDR.AA1H', '190/WSP.AA1H', '190/SD1.AA1H', '190/HUMID.AA1H', '190/NO2.AA1H', '190/PM10.AA1H', '190/PM2.5.AA1H', '190/SO2.AA1H', '190/OZONE.AA1H', '190/CO.AA1H', '206/TEMP.AA1H', '206/RAIN.AA1H', '206/WDR.AA1H', '206/WSP.AA1H', '206/SD1.AA1H', '206/HUMID.AA1H', '206/NO2.AA1H', '206/PM10.AA1H', '206/PM2.5.AA1H', '206/SO2.AA1H', '206/OZONE.AA1H', '206/CO.AA1H')) AND ZR_KOPF.ZRK_BASEPRODUCTION = 1)
```

The error I get is:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The identifier that starts with ''190/TEMP.AA1H', '190/RAIN.AA1H', '190/WDR.AA1H', '190/WSP.AA1H', '190/SD1.AA1H', '190/HUMID.AA1H', '190/NO2.AA1H', '190/PM10.AA' is too long. Maximum length is 128. (103) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Pyodbc version: 4.0.18b1
freetds version: 1.00.48

Any help would be much appreciated
Cheers!

Comment: In cases like this it is usually helpful to post the stack trace and the *exact* error message. Please [edit] your question accordingly. The versions of pyodbc and FreeTDS would also be of interest.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post more of the code. It looks like you're posting just the `WHERE` clause of the query, but more context would be good to see...

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue with pyodbc 4.0.18 and FreeTDS 1.00.48 using the code [here](https://pastebin.com/4SKaJz5y). There must be something else going on. Use my example to try and create a [mcve] that can illustrate the issue and [edit] your question to show your repro code and the output it produces.

Comment: I was also facing the same issue when I was appending data with a double-quote("). But when I append a single quote('). Now it is working fine,

Answer (score 0):

So turns out the spaces between each of the items in the list made all the difference... 
I removed them and the query worked without a hitch.
Thanks for all the help everyone!